# Mysql stored procedure query

Tags: mysql

i have the following stored procedure that returns the sent emails of the latest or last inserted campaigns

"Now my aim to only show the campaigns which have "sent: count greater than "0" how could i make changes to the following sp to do it, because now it is returning all the campaigns including "0" and greater than "0" "..

Code is...

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `couponcrusaderdev`.`sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`anyone`@`000.000.00.00` PROCEDURE `sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`(p_UserID Int(11))
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SELECT EC.*,(Select MailChimpCampaignID from tblcampaignschedule where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID ) as MailChimpCampaignID,(Select  count(MailChimpCampaignID) from tblcampaignschedule) as msent,CT.CampaignType, (Select tblcampaignschedule.ScheduleDateTime from tblcampaignschedule 
where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID  order By ScheduleDateTime desc limit 1) as CampaignDateTime,
(Select Count(*) from tblemailsent ES
inner join tblcampaignschedule CS on CS.CampaignSceduleID= ES.CampaignSceduleID
where ES.Status= 'ProcessedMessage' and CS.CampaignID = EC.CampaignID)as Sent
FROM tblemailcampaign EC
inner join tblcampalgntype  CT on CT.CampaignTypeID= EC.CampaignTypeID
inner join tblcompanies C On EC.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
WHERE (p_UserID = 0 OR C.AddUserID = p_UserID)
 order by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4
;
END$$

DELIMI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **HAVING**

```
 HAVING COUNT(sent) >= 0;
```

Manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Thanks for replying but where should i place this in ny above code can u paste it for me in the above code and resend it...plz i am a beginner and what should be done with the following line.......... order by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4

Comment: And what should be done with the following line.......... order by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4 as by adding HAVING COUNT(sent) >= 0; it returns abnormal results i think it is due to it

Comment: Whether GroupBy should be placed or not if yes than what is the syntax for it??

Comment: Try to use this:  GROUP BY  CampaignDateTime
  HAVING test > 0
  ORDER by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4